# Add a switch case for listener in Android

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, listener

I have one method `onFocusChange()`, this method is used for checking if edittext on my apps is focus as below :

```
nama_pp = (EditText) polis.findViewById(R.id.nama_pp);
nama_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
gelar_pp = (EditText) polis.findViewById(R.id.gelar_pp);
gelar_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
alamat_pp = (EditText) polis.findViewById(R.id.alamat_pp);
alamat_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
kota_pp = (EditText) polis.findViewById(R.id.kota_pp);
kota_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
kdpos_pp = (EditText) polis.findViewById(R.id.kdpos_pp);
kdpos_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

Here is the method:

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    }else{
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    case R.id.alamat_pp:
    if (!hasFocus) {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    } else {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    break;
    case R.id.kota_pp:
    if (!hasFocus) {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    } else {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    break;
    case R.id.kdpos_pp:
    if (!hasFocus) {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    } else {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    break;
    case R.id.telp1_pp:
    if (!hasFocus) {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    } else {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    break;
    case R.id.telp2_pp:
    if (!hasFocus) {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    } else {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    break;
}
```

As you can see, the statement for alamat_pp, kota_pp,kd_pos_pp have the same statement:

```
layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
        }else {
layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
        }
```

If I want to set  my switch for focuschange for listener as `alamat_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);`, how would I write it in my `switch`?

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    }else {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    case R.id.alamat_pp:
    if(!hasFocus){
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
    }else {
        layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
    }
    break;
}
switch(?????){
    case listener:
        if(!hasFocus){
            layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
        }else {
            layout_alamatrmh_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
        }
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Your switch in `onFocusChange` is not syntatically correct.  You may want to look into fixing *that* before deciding if you can use it.

Comment: @makoto i think its right.. i just confuse in "switch(?????)" for listener

Comment: I meant from jump, actually.  You don't have any `case` statements in that code.  I'm not convinced this even compiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //implement the onFocusChange method here
        public void onFocusChange(View v) {
           // Perform action on FocusChange
          switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonplay:
              //Play voicefile
              MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).start();
              break;
            case R.id.buttonstop:
              //Stop MediaPlayer
              MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).stop();
              break;
          }
       }
```

pass button id in case condition....

Comment: i know the method for : switch(v.getId()) my question if, is it possible if i want to switch my listener???